# Dynamic memory allocation | Unable to write on location

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

**NOTE:** Sorry if this is duplicate but i haven't found any case which is similar to mine.

I am working on a C language project and I am not good at this. I am a very noob at dynamic memory allocation. So the issue I am facing is that when I create an instance of a structure which is given below

```
typedef struct temp_ {
    Household data;
    struct temp_ * next;
}Node, *NodePtr;
```

by this way it or many others I have tried so far

```
NodePtr makeNode(Household num){
    NodePtr ptr = (NodePtr) malloc(sizeof(NodePtr));
    ptr->data = num;
    return ptr;
}
```

So I get different types of errors that I can not understand.
If anyone can help it will be a great pleasure.

Comment: What errors do you get? Why do you try to `typedef` a pointer to a struct?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre] and give the exact errors that correspond to that code that you want to ask help for.

Comment: @kaylum
It just stuck and here is one of the message i get
```Exception 0xc0000374 encountered at address 0x76f76c43```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Never hide pointers behing typedefs. It is extremely error prone. In your code you do not allocate enough memory, thus segfault.
2. Use objects not types in `sizeof`

```
typedef struct temp_ {
    Household data;
    struct temp_ * next;
}Node;

Node *makeNode(Household num){
    Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
    if(ptr) ptr->data = num;
    return ptr;
}
```